# How to sort combo box by frequently used?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

So, simple question, I have combo box in my database and I want items that I have selected most frequently to appear first the next time that I add a record.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a Long Integer field to the table consituting the row source for your combobox, and incrementing the value held by such field either on the `AfterUpdate` event of the combobox, or following the main operation being performed by your form.

Then, sort the items in the combobox by this new field in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your combo box selects a lookup value in for a property (PropertyID) that is saved in a table (MainTable).

You can get the number of times this property has been selected with

```
SELECT PropertyID, COUNT(*) AS SelectedTimes
FROM MainTable
GROUP BY PropertyID
```

Now get the sorted lookup table by using this query as sub-query:

```
SELECT L.PropertyID, L.Name
FROM
    LookupTable L
    ( SELECT PropertyID, COUNT(*) AS SelectedTimes
      FROM MainTable
      GROUP BY PropertyID) X
    ON L.PropertyID = X.PropertyID
ORDER BY X.SelectedTimes DESC, L.Name
```

I'm also sorting by name in case two entries have the same count.

Answer (score 0):

As usage may change over time, you should *record the time* when an item was selected. Then you can weight the usage, so recent usage of an item have higher weight than those items used, say, a year ago.

Then you can run a query to list the usage having the most recently used items at top:

```
Select Item, Sum(1 / DateDiff("h", [SelectedTime], Now())) As Usage
From ItemUsage
Group By Item
Order By Sum(1 / DateDiff("h", [SelectedTime], Now())) Desc
```

Of course, this linear weighting may be too simple. You can apply any math to the usage like square or log.